# Use Dropzone.js uploaded file in browser (frontend only)

Tags: javascript, file-upload, frontend, dropzone.js

I'm new to JavaScript, which I use for smaller programs running on browser side. To have a simple and nice drag-and-drop file upload, I want to use Dropzone.js.

With normal file uploads, I can access the file contents by using `onchange` and calling a function to handle the file.

**HTML**:

```
<input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="file_upload" onchange="handleFile();">
```

**JS (handleFile()):**

```
var file = document.getElementById("file_upload").files[0];     
if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        var contents = evt.target.result;
        // use contents
    };
    reader.onerror = function(evt) {alert("Error: Could not read file.")}
}
```

Is something like this also possible with Dropzone.js - only on the frontend side?